# how to pass selected row of gridview in popup window into parent page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 2 pages in asp.net with c# .

a **parent.aspx** and **popup.aspx**.

I passed a querystring(id) into page load of popup.aspx and used function to call row of table base on id and show gridview on popup.aspx.

now I want to select this row, and pass details into text boxes of   parent.aspx that is open now.
 Everything is ok and row of table is passed into text boxes, but it is into new window popup of parent.aspx page, that I don't want this.

I want pass details into this page(parent.aspx) that now is open.

How can I do that.thanks.

below is my code for pass id to pop-up window

```
protected void btn_search_id_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

          string str1 = Encrypt(txt_sh_p.Text);
          btn_search_id.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('popup.aspx?sh_p_=" + str1 + "','Report','width=750,height=500,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no,left=200,top=50'); return false;");

        }
```

my code for reading id and select row and display row in gridview on page load event of popup.aspx:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                DAL.Sab_Ashkh sabt_ashkh = new DAL.Sab_Ashkh();
                List<DAL.Sab_Ashkh> sabt_ashkh_list;

                sabt_ashkh.sh_p = Decrypt(Request.QueryString["sh_p_"]);
                sabt_ashkh_list = sabt_ashkhDB.GetShakh_find(sabt_ashkh.sh_p);
                grid_ashkh.Visible = true;
                grid_ashkh.DataSource = grid_ashkh_list;
                grid_ashkh.DataBind();  

        }
```

and html code for pass row to parent page:

```
 <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="id_shakh" DataNavigateUrlFields="id_shakh" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="parent.aspx?id_shakh={0}"
     HeaderText="id" ItemStyle-Width = "150" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "sh_p" HeaderText ="kod" 
                    >

<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
       </asp:BoundField>
      </Columns>
```

Comment: It is better to do this with JavaScript by local storage and set variable of opener page in popup page like `opener.window.X='xxx'`

Comment: Hi thanks. could you add more detail

Answer (score 0):

I am just telling you how you can change the variable in Main page in popup page like:
Suppose Parent.aspx have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var items =[];   
</script>
```

and in popup.aspx you can do something like :

```
window.opener.items.push(yourSelectedRows);
```

but as another workaround you can also use local storage like:

```
localStorage.setItem("selectedRecords", JSON.stringify(selectedRows));
```

suppose `selectedRows` are your array of object or anything else but as my experience the `selectedRecords` would be accessible in all HTML pages.

hope this help you.

Comment: Hi Aria Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aria Thanks for reply. I pass id by query string into popup window and show gridview . and this script for popup win :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function SetName() {
         if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
             var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txt_id_mah");
             grid = document.getElementById("grid_ashkh");
             var cellPivot;
             if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
                 for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
                     cellPivot = grid.rows[i].cells[1];
                     TXT.value = cellPivot;
                 }
             }
         }
         window.close();
     }
</script>
```

but does not work.